# How to access Google Apps mail from within personal Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

I have a personal Gmail account which I use for personal mails and a Google Apps mail account by my employer which I use for my professional mails. It want to access my Google Apps mails from my personal Gmail account. Can this be done?

It is possible to send mails from other Gmail accounts from one Gmail account (by going to *Settings* → *Accounts and Imports* → *Send Mail As*.

Answer (score 10):

Being an avid user of Gmail and Google Apps myself, I know that it's not as simple as it seems, there's a few steps involved.

You have to redirect all of your work emails to your personal one, verify that you own your personal email, verify (again) that you own your work email so you can send mail through that address and setup a filter so that things don't go into super confusion mode. Long!

Thankfully for you, I'll tell you exactly how you can acomplish this! I'm so nice.

Follow these steps:

1. Login to your work email account
2. Go to `Settings` on the top-right corner of your screen and select `Forwarding and POP/IMAP` -> `Add a forwarding address`
3. Enter your personal email, along with a tag, such as: `username+business@gmail.com` where `business` would be the tag that you associate your work emails to (although this can be anything, make it easy to tell what it is)
4. Login to your personal Gmail account
5. Go to `Settings` -> `Filters` -> `Create a new filter`
6. In the `To:` field, put the address you chose for forwarding your business mail to (in my example, `username+business@gmail.com` and, on the next step, choose to apply a new label (called `Business` for example)
7. Still in `Settings`, go to the `Accounts` tab and `Add another email address you own`
8. Put in your business email (lets say `username@company.com` and also specify the same address as the reply-to address and you can choose to use either SMTP server (I usually don't bother)
9. Accept both authorizations sent to either emails and you're done!

When mail arrives at your work box, it will be redirected to your personal box but with whatever label you chose (in the example, `Business`). Makes it much simpler to organize your mail in a way that won't consume your time searching for it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey! I forwarded the college address to "myusername+college@gmail.com". Now, when I am getting email to my college ID, they are getting forwarded but I don't see any "myusername+college@gmail.com" in that email as "fwd to address"!

Comment: Also found this helpful to remove "on behalf of" message: [SMPT Settings for Google Apps](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/NkOKZ25zQZo)

Answer (score 4):

Under settings on your personal account, setup send as other account. Enter the detail of your Apps account, this will send that account an authorisation request.

When you log into your Apps account, get the code and enter it under your personal account.

Also, in your Apps account you can forward email into your personal account, AND/OR, setup your personal account to pickup email from your Apps account. The pickup will occur every 30 minutes / few hours, the forwarding will be immediate.

Also, log into your Apps account regularly to check the spam folder, unless you set up a filter to never mark any of your email coming into your Apps account as spam.

Comment: "Enable other account to pickup/send mail" is called `Grant access to your account` in the GMail & Google Apps Mail settings: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=138350&ctx=mail&&hl=en

Comment: This is the solution most of my customers are interested in.  They want the ability to 'send' from that account.

Answer (score 4):

Simply, forward your Google Apps account mail to your Gmail using Forwarding facility from Google Apps Mail Setting.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps mail has supported email delegation for a while (as notied by koiyu above -- see http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=138350), and Gmail recently added support as well (http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/12/email-delegation-granting-access-to.html). This should allow you to view each account in a separate tab or window if you wish to.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine if you don't mind having all of your email combined into one inbox. Another way to do this is to just sign into one of your Google accounts, click on your profile photo then click "Add Account" and sign into the other account. You'll have them on two separate tabs but you'll be logged into both and can switch back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

**To add another email ID to your send mail as option in Gmail**

1. Go to Settings (gear icon) → *Settings* → *Accounts and Import* (tab)
2. Send mail as: → Add another email address you own.
3. Fill in the following details in the popup:

   - Server: smtp.gmail.com
   - username: Yourfuliem@ilID
   - password: YourPassword
   - SSL Port 465
     [Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587
     Gmail SMTP port (SSL): 465
     Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required: Yes]

A confirmation mail will be send to the email ID you just added. Click on that link to verify or take the verification code and paste it in the box. You are done.

This will add the new email ID you just added to your send mail as drop down list when you compose a mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Incognito mode in Google Chrome or InPrivate Browsing in IE8 and above (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/features/safer.aspx?tab=6) to view a 2nd account after you've already logged into your 1st account (or view them both in this mode.)

Comment: This could be useful for 2 GMail accounts or 2 Google Apps accounts on the same domain, as they're separate services. Also it really doesn't answer the question: how to access Google Apps Mail from GMail.

Answer (score 0):

### Add additional account identities in the mail settings

Go to *Settings* (gear icon) → *Mail Settings* → *Accounts and Import*

Under the *Send mail as* section click on **Add another email address you own**.

Next:

- Follow the directions until you get to the part where a confirmation email is sent
- Open another tab/window
- Login with the other account
- Open the confirmation email
- Copy the comfirmation code
- Paste it into the popup for the first account

Now, when you goto send an email in the 'From' field you'll have a dropdown menu where you can select which email you want to use.