# Is there a good way to juggling a Google Apps account with a personal one?

Tags: google-workspace, youtube, google-analytics

I have my personal account and a Google Apps account. Despite Google now allowing multiple logins, I'm having trouble making different Google connected services use the right one. Is there a way to:

- Always have YouTube be associated with my personal one so I don't have to log out of the apps one (which seem to log me out of everything)?
- Not have to log out of Google Analytics to switch view from one to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your youtube issue is simple answer of logging in with that account first.

The analytics issue however is the real problem as it doesn't currently support multi-sign

So the only options I can think of are using an private session(or what ever the browsers call it) for the anayltics and do as normal for mail and youtube.

Answer (score 3):

The way I do this is by accessing my google apps emails from my personal gmail account. I simply forward all mails from my apps account to my personal gmail account. This question: [How to access google apps mail from within personal gmail account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9723/how-to-access-google-apps-mail-from-within-personal-gmail-account) should provide you with some other helpful answers as well.